# Where is the girl?

Tags: riddle, cipher

A girl called Claire suddenly disappeared two weeks ago. She left strange notes before she left. Her parents asked everybody to help find their girl.

Last diary entries:

[12.02.2019]
*Prep for mom and dad:

ABCD

AABC

BBCD

CDEF*

[13.02.2019]
*I can't see his face, he always wears black. Maybe he is French?*

[14.02.2019]
*The strange man still follows me.

I hope his favorite color isn't blue because it's part of the key.

I might not see the yellow of the sun again.

My favorite color is the key.

People give it a meaning, it is what I need right now.*

Goodbye Note:

*Nvpt V mfx ovjeetcku

M oaun xlnz kli zge pmikj egeujw xuk jxvrkk*

> Can you decrypt the Goodbye Note based on her diary entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is

> Help I got kidnapped
>  I know that the man lives across the street

The cipher is

> A Vigenère cipher with key "GREEN". I guessed the key by trying a few 'normal' colours (which isn't great, I'll admit...)
>  'People give it a meaning, which is what I need right now': Green is the colour of hope

Comment: Well yeah correct, good job. Maybe this one was a bit too easy.

Comment: @eru-cs I still didn't understand how you solved?

Comment: @ahmed
rot13(Jryy, V gbbx gur fragrapr 'Zl snibhevgr pbybhe vf gur xrl' dhvgr yvgrenyyl: guvf pvcure erdhverf n bar-jbeq qrpelcgvba xrl, naq guvf jbeq vf n pbybhe. V gura fhfcrpgrq vg jnf n IvtraÃ¨er pvcure nf vg'f n irel pbzzba pbqr jubfr xrl vf n fvatyr jbeq. Gura V whfg gevrq n srj pbzzba pbybhef hagvy vg znqr nal frafr. Ohg vs lbh jnag gb fbyir nf vagraqrq:
1)'V ubcr uvf snibevgr pbybe vfa'g oyhr orpnhfr vg'f cneg bs gur xrl.': Va fhofgenpgvir pbybhe flagurfvf, terra = oyhr + lryybj
2)'Crbcyr tvir vg n zrnavat, vg vf jung V arrq evtug abj.': terra vf gur pbybe bs ubcr.)

Comment: @eru-cs No help. Which language is this?

Comment: Rot13 is Caesar cipher with offset 13 (it's commonly used on this site to avoid spoilers in comments). To code or decode just shift each letter by 13 positions. If you type "rot13" into your search engine, you'll find online decoders

Comment: rot13(Ohg ubj qvq lbh qrpbqr gur tbbq olr abgr)?